# Retrieving list of names of branches from repository that have been inactive/not committed to in the last 2 months

Tags: bash, git, version-control, git-branch

I'm trying to write a bash script to clean up some stuff and one part of it is to sort through all of the branches I have. I'm trying to get a list of the names of branches in a repo that haven't been commited to in the last 2 months. I'll store this list in a variable and go through each one that I can delete.

So far I have been doing the following:

```
git clone -q --depth 1 --bare --no-single-branch **REMOTE_URL** tmp/tmp-location
cd tmp/tmp-location
git branch --format='%(color:bold green) %(refname:short) %(color:white) %(committerdate)' --sort=-committerdate
```

Or I also did the following:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(HEAD) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) - (%(color:green)%(committerdate:relative)%(color:reset))'
```

This has been great at listing all of the branches and ordering by committer date, but I don't know how to get a list of branches with a committer date older than 2 months.

**Or even better**
Is it possible to check the last commit date of a specific branch name, not just all branches like in the above solutions?

Comment: Do you need to clean remote bare git or local one or both?

Comment: Basically I have a second list of branches. This list does not contain the last commit dates of these branches. I am trying to cross refrence this list onto the one above that I'm trying to retrieve. I will then use this info on which of these are older than 2 months to automatically delete custom routes a bit further on in the bash script this is for.

Comment: Side note: if you're just after the metadata in the commit itself, you can skip the trees, do your clone `--bare --filter=tree:0`.

Comment: Ah that's interesting @jthill. Sounds like that'd fit what I'm trying to do in terms of cloning. Does this download less compared to a git clone --depth 1 directory in general?

Comment: Very much less, try both and see. The convenience commands expect full commits and will wind up fetching the contents anyway, at retail prices, so this use is often a bad trade, but here it's a real winner.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Very sorry for taking so long to come back to this question. I became busy during the weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get just the needed data, fast:

```
git clone --filter=tree:0 --depth=1 --bare  --no-single-branch --no-tags \
        u://r/l `mktemp -d`
cd $_
```

and now you've got just the minimal needed metadata for just the branch tips. Getting your selection formatted all pretty is

```
for rev in `git rev-list --branches --no-walk --before=midnight.2.months.ago`
do
        git branch --points-at $rev --format='%(refname:short)'
done
```

and season that last format to taste of course

Comment: The backquote is used in the old-style command substitution. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: I would have just used `git log --no-walk --oneline --until=2.months.ago --branches --remotes` since the question sounds like the result is intended for human consumption, not for scripting. Nevertheless +1 for the suggestion to throw in `--no-walk`.

Comment: @j6t That's what I tried first too, but when I did it started fetching more.  Not sure what it was trying to calculate, <shrug/>

Comment: @j6t p.s. forgot to mention the pretty-format decorators also helpfully mark every one of the branch tips as grafted.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do to list inactive branches since 2 months for every local branches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git checkout master
for branch in $(git branch | tr -d '\*'); do
    [[ $branch == master ]] && continue
    git checkout $branch &>/dev/null
    num=$(git log --since="$(LC_ALL=C date -d '2 month ago')" master.. | grep -c '^commit ')
    ((num==0)) && echo "$branch"
done

git checkout master
```